# PHP/Mysql: Full text search results returns more results (counted), then is shown in while loop.

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search

I have the following code.

When a user enters the a term... sometimes the totalRows_titles returns more than the records displayed on the page. (I think I am echoing the wrong values, but I guess I stared at this too long).

You can see an example here (It will say 5 results found, but only displays 4):

http://libapps.libraries.uc.edu/main/databases/database-results.php?search=naxos&go=Go

The missing fifth item is the one we expect to see, and is called "Naxos Music Library". 
It shows as a result, for example, on this search, so it is in the database:

http://libapps.libraries.uc.edu/main/databases/database-results.php?search=naxos+music&go=Go

Here is the code:

```
   $search = $_GET['search'];
      if(isset($_GET['search']))
       {
  if ( $titles = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM arti WHERE MATCH(name, description, url)   AGAINST('$search')ORDER BY name ASC"))
          {
 $row_titles = mysql_fetch_assoc($titles);
   $totalRows_titles = mysql_num_rows($titles);
         echo '<h4 >'. $totalRows_titles . '&nbsp;titles were found matching the entry &nbsp; <em>'. $search .'</em></h4>';
   while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($titles))
        {
      echo '<p><b>'. $row['name'].'</b></br>'.$row['description'].'</br><a href="http://proxy.libraries.uc.edu/login?url='.$row['url'].'">Connect</a></p>';
       }
   }
  else
         {
    echo "mysql:".(mysql_error ());
         }
     } 
  ?>
```

Comment: is there any specific reason for `$row_titles = mysql_fetch_assoc($titles);` before the while loop ?

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty because that call removes the first row of the result ...

Comment: I had thought that was to get the total, but now that I look at it, I think I may have messed that up. I think I see what you mean.

Comment: Thanks, wow, that fixed it. Can you explain to me why that took out the first row? (learning)

Comment: in the first call it sets the cursor pointer to the first row and when you call again it moves to the 2nd and so on, that why you use while loop and until the cursor does not go till end the loop will execute and you display the data.

Comment: Fist of all, put $search = $_GET['search'] within your if statement. Just a best practice, no reason to pointlessly assign a variable.